# mysql count how many times one field links to another

Tags: mysql

If I have the following table:

```
id  |  ref
1       b
4       c
2       a
3       b
1       b
3       b
```

how do I count how many **unique** instances of `id` have `b` as their reference?  The query I have now is:

```
select id, ref, count(ref) from table group by ref;
```

but this shows me the number of times each `ref` exists in the table.  What I'm looking for this is:

```
id  |  ref  |  count
1       b        2  /*id 1, id 3*/
4       c        1  /*id 4 */
2       a        1  /*id 2 */
```

## Edit

I actually need to see all the lines still - not a `group by` summary of them, so I need it to look like this:

```
id  |  ref  |  count
1       b        2 /* id 1, id 3 */
4       c        1 /* id 4 */
2       a        1 /* id 2 */
3       b        2 /* id 1, id 3 */
1       b        2 /* id 1, id 3 */
3       b        2 /* id 1, id 3 */
```

Comment: SELECT id, ref, count(*) FROM `table` GROUP BY id WHERE ref='b'

Comment: `count(id)` will give me the count of each time an individual id exists - so if `1` exists 12 times, it will say 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ref, count(distinct id) from table group by ref;
```

This will give you a count of distinct id by ref.

```
select ref, count(*) from table group by ref;
```

This will give you number of records by ref.

EDIT:

Try this to get the output you desire.

```
select t.*, m.counter
from table t 
join (
   select ref, count(distinct id) as counter
   from table group by ref
) m on t.ref = m.ref
```

Example on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b93c/2

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for - so thank you.  I changed my question a bit because I realized it was wrong.  How do I still get all the lines to show, just with an additional count column.  If I use any `group by` it's grouping by that reference and removing columns in favor of the count, but if I don't use a `group by` at all, I just get 1 line of data.

Comment: I've added a SQL example link and the SQL itself that will help.

Comment: This query worked - but it took 1700 seconds to run on my two 1.5m+ row tables.  If I use a `group by`, it takes about 4 seconds, but doesn't include ALL the rows - just a summary.  Can you think of any other way that this idea could be run in a quicker manner?

Comment: Do you have an index on ref and id? If not, do `create index idx_tablename_ref_id on tablename(ref, id);` and re-run the query. Let me know if you see a difference.

Comment: I had indexes on both tables that included these fields, (e.g. - `ref, cost` and `id, cost`), but no index of JUST those fields.  I went back and created  a new index on both tables for JUST these fields individually, but it did not decrease the run time.  Still about 22 minutes for the query to run....

Comment: Both tables? I thought you had just one table. Can you open a new question with outputs from `show create table table1` and same for table2? It might help formulate a better answer. If your data is not sensitive or can be scrambled, a zipped data dump might help additionally.

Comment: Yeah - I had to join in data from another table and it made the query a lot more complex.  I apologize for continuing to change this up on you!  I know that's a big stackoverflow no-no :)  I have posted a new question here that details my EXACT issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284598/mysql-retrieving-all-rows-while-also-using-summaries

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ref, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY ref
```

`DISTINCT` means it won't count duplicate IDs.