# mysql retrieving all rows while also using summaries

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT name, APN, BPN, count(APN), min(aCost), min(bCost), ceil(avg(aQty)), 
max(aQty), sum(bShipped), 
CONCAT(truncate((avg(aResale)-avg(aCost))/avg(aResale),2) * 100,'%'), code FROM
(SELECT name, APN, BPN, aCost, aQty, code
    FROM table_1
    WHERE customer = '12345' AND
    aDate >= '2013-01-01' and
    aDate <= '2015-12-12') as qh
INNER JOIN (SELECT CPN, bCost, bResale, bShipped from table_2 
WHERE customer = '12345') as ih
ON qh.APN = ih.CPN
WHERE bShipped > 0
GROUP BY qh.APN;
```

What I need out of this is for EACH row to be output, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Right now, I'm getting this:

```
NAME   |   APN  |  BPN   |  APN Count
asdf       001     555      3  /*summary of APN 001*/
qere       002     865      1  /*summary of APN 002*/
rtrt       003     123      2  /*summary of APN 003*/
```

Because of the `group by`, I'm getting a **summary** of `qh.APN`, but if I don't use any `group by` statement, I get 1 line only in my result.

I am looking to have this `APN Count` column, while at the *same time* showing all the rows - not having any values summarized.  Like this:

```
NAME   |   APN  |  BPN   |  APN Count
asdf       001     555      3  /*Individual record, with count too*/
asdf       001     862      3  /*Individual record, with count too*/
asdf       001     999      3  /*Individual record, with count too*/
qere       002     865      1  /*Individual record, with count too*/
rtrt       003     123      2  /*Individual record, with count too*/
rtrt       003     456      2  /*Individual record, with count too*/
```

I need to see each individual record that makes up the `APN Count` column because I need to see each `BPN`, not just one summary row.  I am writing this with a `group by` right now because seeing the summarized data is better than *nothing*, and because I don't know the correct syntax to use here to get the result I want.

Comment: GROUP BY qh.APN, qh.BPN;

Comment: Nope.  I still get one summary line per `APN`

Comment: `JOIN` it back to original table

Comment: `aResale`  belongs to which table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join table 1 with your aggregate query as a subquery.

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.apn, t1.bpn, t1.code, t2.*
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT APN, count(APN) AS APN_count, min(aCost) AS min_aCost, min(bCost) AS min_bCost, ceil(avg(aQty)) AS avgQty, 
    max(aQty) AS maxQty, sum(bShipped) AS sum_bShipped, 
    CONCAT(truncate((avg(aResale)-avg(aCost))/avg(aResale),2) * 100,'%') AS avg_Margin FROM
    (SELECT name, APN, BPN, aCost, aQty, code
        FROM table_1
        WHERE customer = '12345' AND
        aDate >= '2013-01-01' and
        aDate <= '2015-12-12') as qh
    INNER JOIN (SELECT CPN, bCost, bResale, bShipped from table_2 
    WHERE customer = '12345') as ih
    ON qh.APN = ih.CPN
    WHERE bShipped > 0
    GROUP BY qh.APN) AS t2
ON t1.APN = t2.APN
```

Comment: holy crap that's a complicated query, but yes, it WORKS.  Thanks for responding both to this one, and to my original post.  I really appreciate the work you put into helping me understand this quandary I was in. :)  And props on figuring out average margin :)

Comment: not sure, that it works...`WHERE customer = '12345' AND
        aDate >= '2013-01-01' and
        aDate <= '2015-12-12'` is in subquery. so it could select base of 100 records. but outside you use no `WHERE` clause so the base will bee like 1 000 000 records. is it required result? imho - not. because `ON  t1.APN = t2.APN` not cutting extra periods and extra customers

Comment: I'm using the subquery as a way to weed out what I compare between the two tables in the first place.  I want to select only the APNs from table_1 that exist inside the subquery `where customer = and date =` PRIOR to comparing that to data from table_2 - otherwise I'm comparing EVERYTHING in table_1 to EVERYTHING in table_2.

Comment: But @Barmar query is doing a bit different than you explain now. *EVERYTHING in table_1 to EVERYTHING in table_2* if you need this you should move `INNER JOIN  table_2` out from subquery. But I don't beleive in your *VERYTHING in table_1 to EVERYTHING in table_2* because I see **from table_2 WHERE customer = '12345'** `WHERE` is not equal to `EVERYTHING`

Comment: You should take out the `t1.name, t1.apn, t1.bpn, t1.code` in that first line so you don't get duplication in your ouput.  All of those columns are already going to output from the first JOIN.

Comment: @Alex - no, you're correct.  Poor choice of words on my part.  I am still using the subquery to narrow down what I am searching FROM table_1 AGAINST table_2.  I don't want to search ALL APNs against data in table_2 `where customer = 12345 and date =...`, I want to search only APNs that belong to a particular customer and which are between particular dates to that table_2 subset.  So it seems that this is working and doing what I want.  Sorry if I didn't explain that well.

Comment: try to change period to normal one like just 1 month. you will be surprised I guess. now your period seems to cover all records - so you don't see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way is to join your result set to some *original* table. In your case I am not sure what is an original one but it could be something like:

```
SELECT t.*,
       t_agregated.*
FROM table_1 t
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT t1.APN,  
       count(t1.APN), 
       min(t1.aCost), 
       min(bCost), 
       ceil(avg(t1.aQty)), 
       max(aQty), 
       sum(bShipped), 
       CONCAT(truncate((avg(t1.aResale)-avg(t1.aCost))/avg(t1.aResale),2) * 100,'%')
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2
ON t1.APN = t2.CPN
   AND t2.bShipped > 0
WHERE t1.customer = '12345' AND
    aDate >= '2013-01-01' and
    aDate <= '2015-12-12'
GROUP BY t1.APN) t_agregated
ON t.APN = t_agregated.APN
WHERE t.customer = '12345' AND
    t.aDate >= '2013-01-01' and
    t.aDate <= '2015-12-12'
```

But I am pretty sure, your goal is far from here. You should better post raw data source and expected result set. The good way to ask questions here is to provide sqlfiddle with table schemes and data samples.

Comment: I'll include an SQL fiddle next time - I've got to change so much data as it's sensitive, that it's easier for me to just post "fake" data that looks real, along with an expectation of what I'm after.  I will definitely keep this in mind for my next post - and I will look through the query you've posted here so I can learn from it.  Thank you Alex!