# Count how many times certain fields in records with repeating values are found (or not found) in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

First of all, I wish to say hi to the community here. The posts here have been a great help with VBA but this is my first question ever. I have a task that I need to solve in SQL (in MS Access) but it's sort of new to me and the task seems to be too complex.

I have a table in Access with the following structure(let's call it `Tinvoices`):

```
invoice | year | date       | company | step | agent
5110001 | 2019 | 15/01/2019 | 1201    | 0    | John
5110001 | 2019 | 15/01/2019 | 1201    | 1    | Jack
5110002 | 2019 | 10/02/2019 | 1202    | 0    | John
5110002 | 2019 | 10/02/2019 | 1202    | 1    | Jack
5110002 | 2019 | 10/02/2019 | 1202    | 2    | Daniel
5110002 | 2019 | 10/02/2019 | 1202    | 3    | John
5110003 | 2019 | 12/03/2019 | 1205    | 0    | Jack
5110003 | 2019 | 12/03/2019 | 1205    | 1    | Daniel
5110003 | 2019 | 12/03/2019 | 1205    | 2    | David
```

This table relates to actions on invoices. Invoices and their related data are repeated with each step.
There is another table, which contains agents belonging to a certain department (let's call it `Tdeptusers`):

```
agent
John
Jack
```

What I need to do is the following. Have distinct lines for the invoices (the most unique key is combining the invoice, year and company) and counting in separate steps have been done by users in the `Tdeptusers` table and how many by users who are not in `Tdeptusers`. Something like this:

```
invoice | year | month | company | actionsByOurDept | actionsByOthers
5110001 | 2019 | 1     | 1201    | 2                | 0
5110002 | 2019 | 2     | 1202    | 3                | 1
5110003 | 2019 | 3     | 1205    | 1                | 2
```

I'm kind of a beginner, so you'll have to excuse me in providing usable codes. Being a complete beginner, I got stuck after the absolute basics. I have stuff like this:

```
SELECT 
invoice, 
year, 
DatePart("m", Date) AS month, 
company, 
Sum(IIf(i.agent IN(d.agent), 1, 0)) AS actionsByOurDept, 
Sum(IIf(i.agent IN(d.agent), 0, 1)) AS actionsByOthers
FROM Tinvoices AS i, Tdeptusers AS d
GROUP BY invoice, year, DatePart("m", Date), company;
```

This doesn't give back the desired result, mostly not in actionsByOthers, instead I get huge numbers. Maybe something similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33269655/9018796) might work but I haven't been able to do it.
Much appreciation for the help, folks.

Comment: No JOIN condition needed?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Probably I should do something like `JOIN`ing (or `LEFT JOIN`ing) the two tables by the agent name, then count in that column for each invoice how many times there is a match and how many times it remained `null`. Just need to figure out that'd look like, I'll keep trying :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proper standard explicit *JOIN* syntax :

```
SELECT i.invoice, year, DatePart("m", i.Date) AS month, i.company, 
      SUM( IIF(d.agent IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) ) AS actionsByOurDept, 
      SUM( IIf(d.agent IS NULL, 1, 0) ) AS actionsByOthers
FROM Tinvoices AS i LEFT JOIN
     Tdeptusers AS d
     ON d.agent = i.agent
GROUP BY i.invoice, i.year, DatePart("m", i.Date), i.company;
```

Comment: Seems like, I was only missing the main point :) Your solution is similar to that of Gordon Linoff and it works just as well, cheers Yogesh (I can only mark 1 solution, I suppose - I also cannot upvote yet but I tried :) )

Comment: @ÁdámVárhegyi-Miłoś. . . Yes answer is same.But you can see the difference in minutes posting the answer.

Comment: Indeed, your answer arrived by less than a minute before Gordon's solution, so it's only fair that I mark yours as the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`:

```
SELECT invoice, year, DatePart("m", Date) AS month, company, 
       COUNT(d.agent) AS actionsByOurDept, 
       SUM(IIF(d.agent IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS actionsByOthers
FROM Tinvoices AS i LEFT JOIN
     Tdeptusers AS d
     ON d.agent = i.agent
GROUP BY invoice, year, DatePart("m", Date), company;
```

You can directly count your department's users using `COUNT()`.

Comment: I was really over-complicating it. Cheers.